# Замена цифры в бинарном файле

Tags: c++, файлы, binary

В программе нужно заменить цифру в бинарном файле. Возникла проблема с функцией замены. Считывает не цифру, а невесть что, к тому же не переходит на новую позицию, сохраняя первое мегадлинное значение, которого быть не должно.

например, записали в файл:

```
0 3 
третий 2 
пятый 0
первый 4
второй 1
```

если я решаю добавить `четвёртый 2`, двойка около `третий` должна измениться на 5.

Код:

```
void swap_val(fstream&tab){
    int buf;
    tab.open("tab.bin", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
    for(int i = 21; i < block*(k-1); i+=block){
        tab.seekg(i);
        tab.read((char*)&buf, 4);
        cout << "buf: " << buf << endl;
        if(buf == val){
            tab.seekg(i);
            tab.write((char*)&val, 4);
            tab.seekg(block*k - 4);
            tab.write((char*)&buf, 4);
            cout << "Check" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    tab.close();
}
```

Comment: Судя по содержанию, Ваш файл не бинарный, а текстовый

Comment: судя по используемым мною функциям и режиму открытия, вы ошибаетесь

Comment: Режим открытия влияет только на интерпретацию переводов строк, и ни на что больше. А какие функции вы используете на формат файла не влияет тем более. Файл ваш текстовый - если судить по тому, что вы же и приводите, символ '2' занимает в нём ровно один байт, и обращаться с его значением нужно как с текстом. Кстати, подумайте, что случится, если вместо числа из одного символа (0-9) там окажется больше цифр (10-...).

Comment: где вы видите, чтобы "2" занимал один байт? я записываю int в 4 байта и считываю столько же.

Comment: В тексте вашего вопроса приведена структура файла, там и вижу.

Comment: @annussaa приведите код, которым вы изначально пишете в файл (его минимальны аналог). сейчас совсем непонятно что у вас там в файле лежит.